# Global Controllers not working on AngularJS 1.3

Tags: angularjs

The following code works alright in Angular 1.2, but it doesnt work on 1.3

What should I change to make it work on 1.3?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="">

<head>
<title>MyApp</title>
</head>

<body>

<div class="wrapper" ng-controller="SimpleController">

    <div>Name:</div>
    <div>
        <input type="text" ng-model="filterword">
    </div>

    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="person in contacts | filter: filterword | orderBy: 'name'" >{{ person.name }} lives in {{ person.city }}</li>
    </ul>

</div>

<script>
    var SimpleController = function($scope){
        $scope.contacts = [

            {name: 'Dave',
            city: 'Dresden'},

            {name:'John',
            city: 'Madrid'},

            {name:'Jane',
            city: 'Berlin'}
        ];
    }
</script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Controller not defined error in simple AngularJS example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26517501/controller-not-defined-error-in-simple-angularjs-example)

Comment: You are right. I will reformulate the question, and answer it mayself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out, as explained on [this other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26517501/controller-not-defined-error-in-simple-angularjs-example) that from version 1.3, global controllers are not allowed, since they produce quite messy code.

[More info](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/3f2232b5a181512fac23775b1df4a6ebda67d018)